# Getting output from executable called from command line

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file, cmd

So I've got a node.js program that just runs a system command using `.exec()` from `child_process`
Everything works if the executed command is something like: `CALL test.bat`. The output from this batch file is seen by the NodeJS program.
But when I try calling an executable like `CALL someExecutable.exe` it doesn't work.
Running this executable on its own outputs stuff to its console.

How can I intercept the console output of this executable?

Comment: Do you can redirect the output from that program, when starting from the console?  `prog > my.log`

Comment: I got one of the executables to work with my program. I tried another one but i think it creates a new window for its console. So the log file is empty when running the second one

Comment: Since you say that you know it is using `.exec()`, do you have source code of the program?

Comment: My program uses exec for launching the target program and some extra commands. The code for that is here https://github.com/Maticzpl/Local-GSM/blob/main/src/server/console.ts My goal is to get the console output of the target program im executing without modifying it.